# What does the notation $(1^-,2^-)$ mean in the ground-state nuclear spin of lithium $10$?

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-spin

I am trying to get to grips with nuclear spin. However I note that many of the spin of isotopes can have many results. For example, if one looks on [the Wikipedia page for the isotopes of lithium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_lithium#Table), the spin of $^{10}$Li, ground state, is quoted as $(1^-,2^-)$. And it says

> The values of spin with weak assignment arguments are enclosed in parentheses.

So what does that mean, we don't know what the spin is? Does $^{10}$Li have two spins?

Comment: Going back to F.C. Barker and G. T. Hickey, J. PHys. G: Nucl. Phys 3(2) L23-L25 (1977), one finds "The lowest non-normal parity level of $^{10}$Li ... is expected to be $2^{-}$, with a $1^{-}$ level about 1MeV higher." Experimentally what it means is that it is hard to make, and know you made, a $^{10}$Li in the ground state so you can measure the properties.

Comment: @JonCuster The argument that the levels are too close looks a bit shaky to me. A [more recent review](http://dx.doi.org10.1016/j.nuclphysa.2004.09.059) (p. 261) has the same uncertain identification, with another level of uncertain parity about 1.4 MeV above the ground state, but it has levels of well-resolved spin between the two.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be pretty standard notation. The nuclide charts for [the IAEA Nuclear Data Services](https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html), [KAERI](http://atom.kaeri.re.kr/nuchart/?zlv=1#) and the [National Nuclear Data Center](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/chart/reCenter.jsp?z=3&n=7) all give the $J^P$ of $^{10}\mathrm{Li}$ as $(1^-,2^-)$, brackets and all. For example, the NNDC provides a [list of levels](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/chart/getdataset.jsp?nucleus=10LI&unc=nds) for this nuclide which does provide spin information for other levels, but again the bracketed notation for the ground state of the nuclide.

I think the clearest explanation of this notation is in the [NNDC glossary](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/chart/help/glossary.jsp):

> $J\pi \quad\quad\ $Meaning
>
> (1,2+) $\quad$     We think that the spin and parity are either 1+ or 1- or 2+, but we are not 100% sure

This is backed up by the IAEA NDS [guide to the tables](https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/guide.html#quantities), which reads

> $J^\pi$ Angular momentum and parity of the state. Values between round brackets are uncertain (based on weak arguments, see the ENSDF [manual](https://www-nds.iaea.org/public/documents/ensdf/ensdf-manual.pdf) pag. 103), values between square brakets are assumed from theory.

In essence: there simply isn't enough information available on the spin of this nucleus to tell whether its ground state has $J=1$ or $J=2$.

Comment: Given the listed half-lives in the $10^{-21}$ second range, any guess on a ground state would seem to be a good guess at some level. After doing whatever you have to do to land on a $^{10}$Li nucleus in the first place, the chance that it is in the ground state, given how close the other states are, is pretty slim.

Comment: Also, the A=10 nuclear data sheet hosted at http://www.tunl.duke.edu/nucldata/chain/10.shtml says that 'the general consensus for the $^{10}$Li ground state configuration is that a broad s-wave neutron resonance couples with the $3-/2$ $^{9}$Li ground state to give either $1^{-}$ or $2^{-}$ resonance'. It also states that the nucleus is 'neutron unbound by $25 \pm 15$keV (hence the short lifetime!).

Comment: @Jon That was my first reaction too but I'm not sure it holds. The Wikipedia page goes all the way up to lithium 12, with lithium 11 rather long lived, so I don't think the argument that lithium 10 is "too big to probe accurately" holds, at least without additional information. Similarly, there's unambiguous spin assignments at similar half-lives in that and other isotopes of lithium, so the lifetime can't be that troublesome. (You're likely to be probing this as a resonance in an accelerator experiment to begin with, I imagine.)

Comment: That said, I can well imagine that an odd-odd nuclide with a strong n/p imbalance would be an awkward and unstable system to probe, particularly if it's got one of two neutrons way off in a halo and ready to pack their bags and bugger off at a moment's notice.

Comment: Indeed. The TUNL data sheet summarizes the various experiments, and there is lots of handwaving/uncertainty going on. And TUNL seems to prefer to use 'unnatural-parity' rather than non-normal.